# Why does Oracle convert U+2002 to U+0020 when loading UTF8 data?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, character-encoding, plsql

When converting blob data to clob data using UTF8 as the charset,
it appears that Oracle (11gR2) converts the bytes 0xE2 0x80 0x82 to 0x20.
Is this, as I suspect, plain wrong? Even maybe a bug?

I need to edit clobs containing UTF8 encoded data while preserving the original charachters (all of them, especially EN space).

FYI: 0xE2 0x80 0x82 is the "EN Space" while 0x20 is a "Normal Space"

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1020356

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192

```
declare
    v_clob                  clob;
    v_clob_content          varchar2(8);
    v_content_ok            varchar2(64);
    v_content_bad           varchar2(64);
    v_blob                  blob;
    v_raw                   raw(8);

    v_c_dst_offset          pls_integer := 1;
    v_c_src_offset          pls_integer := 1;
    v_c_ctx                 pls_integer := 0;
    v_c_warn                pls_integer;
begin

    -- Create temporary lobs and cache them
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob,true);
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob,true);

    -- Write 0xE2 0x80 0x82 to the BLOB
    v_raw := hextoraw('E2') || hextoraw('80') || hextoraw('82');
    dbms_lob.write(v_blob,utl_raw.length(v_raw),1,v_raw);

    -- Convert the BLOB to CLOB using AL32UTF8 as encoding
    dbms_lob.converttoclob(
       v_clob,
       v_blob,
       dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob),
       v_c_dst_offset,
       v_c_src_offset, 
       nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'),
       v_c_ctx,
       v_c_warn);

    -- Put the CLOB contents into a varchar2
    v_clob_content := dbms_lob.substr(v_clob,dbms_lob.getlength(v_clob));   

    -- Output the HEX value of respectively the BLOB content and the CLOB content
    select rawtohex(v_clob_content) into v_content_bad from dual;
    select rawtohex(v_raw) into v_content_ok from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('[' || v_content_bad || ']');
    dbms_output.put_line('[' || v_content_ok || ']');

    -- Release resources
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_clob);
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
end;
/
```

Outputs :

```
[20]
[E28082]

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: CLOBs are frequently used for storing SQL queries.  The conversion "EN Space" to "Normal Space" is probably done because "EN Space" may not be interpreted as a space by SQL parser.

Comment: I disagree, even if CLOBs can be used to store SQL queries, it is hardly a sufficient reason to change the contents of the clob. Furthermore, CLOBs are certainly not intended to solely hold SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your database is probably not be running under a `AL32UTF8` character set?

ie:

```
SQL> col value format a20
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         UTF8

SQL> declare
  2      v_clob                  clob;
  3      v_clob_content          varchar2(8);
  4      v_content_ok            varchar2(64);
  5      v_content_bad           varchar2(64);
  6      v_blob                  blob;
  7      v_raw                   raw(8);
  8
  9      v_c_dst_offset          pls_integer := 1;
 10      v_c_src_offset          pls_integer := 1;
 11      v_c_ctx                 pls_integer := 0;
 12      v_c_warn                pls_integer;
 ...
 46  end;
 47  /
[E28082]
[E28082]

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

vs running in a non al32utf8 database:

```
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         UTF8
NLS_CHARACTERSET               WE8ISO8859P15

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2      v_clob                  clob;
...
 47  /
[BF]
[E28082]
```

the lob got converted on my western ISO database. if you need to keep `AL32UTF8` in a non binary datatype, ensure you have your database running under that characterset.

Comment: Thanks, as a side question : I cannot change the database characterset, is there no other option?

Comment: @CharlesV.G. the only other thing is the NLS characterset i.e. used with `NVARCHAR2`/`NCLOB`/`NCHAR` datatypes, but these are limited to `UTF8`/`UTF16` (not quite AL32UTF8 so youd probably still get some issues. Your DBA can change the NLS characterset without rebuilding the whole db. Other than that, no as the db would always convert the data when stored in non-binary forms.